# Clear way to skip the first element in an index based for loop

Tags: php, loops

I have a for loop where I must skip the first element in a zero-based array.

Which of these shows my intentions more clearly?

```
for($i=1 ; $i < count(array) ; $i++){
    array[$i];
}
```

or

```
for($i=0+1 ; $i < count(array) ; $i++){
    array[$i];
}
```

Comment: Neither, `$i=2-1` is the superior way. :/

Comment: I'd probably go for the first option and add a comment to explain why the first element has to be skipped.

Comment: When you ask a question using the word "better," you must also explain, *specifically,* what "better" means to you, without resorting to tautologies like "best practice."  This particular question is only answerable because the "correct" solution is readily apparent.

Comment: Clearness is what I am aiming for, I edited the question. Is that any clearer?

Comment: @TomasZubiri could you give some context as to why you want to exclude the first element specifically? Is the first element ignored? Or is the first element treated differently than the others outside the loop? what's the motivation behind this.

Comment: Not using PHP is the superior way.

Comment: The first one is perfectly readable, but another programmer reading the code may think it's a typing error. I would make it clear by using a constant, maybe `START_FROM_SECOND_ELEMENT` - then the choice of starting index 1 looks much more on purpose.

Comment: Does PHP have a foreach construct? You could do `foreach ($i in range(1, count))` (whatever that looks like in PHP). Or something like `foreach ($item in array.skip(1))` which is what a C# person would do.

Comment: Would not be easier just to make a subset with the valid entries and just iterate over the subset? If problem is naming vars, naming a subset make more sense than to think hilsrious names for a mere index!!! It's just a index!!! Idx, index, I, this var as no functional meaning, it's on the subset the real meaning.

Answer (score 23):

I hate both.

Who said you could use magic numbers?  If you're going to start at an offset of 1 how about telling us WHY you're starting at an offset of 1.  Adding an equally magic zero explains nothing to me.

Is this the payload offset? Is this some pascal string you're converting to a null terminated c string? Please tell us what is going on.

Sorry, but I've wasted much of my career decoding pointless mysteries like this and my patience for them has worn thin.  Is **a variable with a decent name** really to much to ask?

By decent name I mean a name that explains WHY we're skipping the first element.  Not something that simply says THAT we're skipping the first element.  The 1 told me that on it's own.

Comment: How about $i or $index?

Comment: @TomasZubiri How do those names explain in anyway why you started at 1?

Comment: 0 and 1 are not magic numbers.

Comment: @user949300 Oh they certainly are here.  They are simply numbers that occasionally aren't magical. Just because 2 is always a magic number doesn't mean that 1 is never a magic number.  The magic comes from missing meaning.  What the heck does starting at a 1 offset mean here?  What good does adding a 0 do here? Oh yes these numbers are certainly magical here.  I can see the pixie dust dripping off of them.

Comment: Sure, I'll start defining `static final int LONELIEST_NUMBER = 1` in all my Java code.  :-)  That said, on further thought I'd like to undownvote your answer but can't unless you edit it.  Silly SO rule?

Comment: @Gusdor, it's good you do not have the rep then as this is a superb answer. Sadly crap like "I'll start defining `static final int LONELIEST_NUMBER = 1`" shows that some simply don't understand the sensible advice contained here.

Comment: While I certainly can appreciate the rant here, is there any advice? Could you expand on what you would think is a better option? Really saying "don't do either" doesn't help the OP understand how to do it better. Please update your answer with what you would consider an acceptable way of approaching the problem. I use the OP's (first) example quite often in code and with an implicit understanding of an array's lower bounds in a particular language I've never found understanding that type of construct difficult.

Comment: @RonBeyer, The combination of a loop skipping the first element and a variable called `array` are the problem. What is it about `array`, or the purpose of the loop, that means the 1st element must be skipped? Let's assume the first element of the array indicates how many elements contain meaningful data. Create a function that describes this in its name and put the OP's code within it. Then `1` makes sense. But all too often, such random loops starting at `1` will start 300 lines through a massive function and we're really be looping over `loop`. Then, it's a pure magic number.

Comment: I feel like variable name fails to address the purpose. Strictly speaking, the name should speak for itself, not necessarily its origin. Such examples of a good name would be `i` or `index` or anything along those lines. Almost all programming language had a special sort of syntax for describing this extra kind of information, and I'm slightly disappointed it wasn't mention: **Comments**.

Comment: @DavidArno I guess that is where my confusion is, I'm assuming that for the purpose of the example the OP's actual code doesn't say `array` but something meaningful. My own coding standards don't allow 300+ line massive functions and the data contained in the arrays (along with the names of arrays) is usually well defined such that creating a new function specifically for skipping the first element would be superfluous. I'm just not sure its black-and-white given well defined data and descriptive names.

Comment: @David Arno, there are only 6 words of advice is this ranty post, (OP highlighted them) and they may or may not be relevant, as `i` is frequently a perfectly good array index.  And note the smiley face in the comment you call "crap", which was clearly humor that you missed.

Comment: @IdanArye those are not descriptive names, those are magic names

Comment: Starting a loop at 0 or 1 is immediately understandable. Where would you define the constant, and how would you name it? That is, in a beneficial way - just adding loopStartIndex right before the loop obviously doesn't improve the code.

Comment: @Eiko starting a loop at 42 is immediately understandable. Except WHY it's starting at 42.  If you start it at 1 please imagine that other people would like to be told WHY you didn't start at 0.  If you can find a better way than a variable with a decent name than fine.  But never assume that since you know why everyone knows why.  That's lazy and wrong.

Comment: @CandiedOrange The question wasn't about 42. It was about 1. There is much less magic in 0 and 1 than in 42. Is `for ($i = $indexOfSecondElement; ... )` any better? Is it easier to read or understand? I think you are over-generalizing the question here. BTW: How do you replace `0` in your own code?

Comment: @Eiko no there isn't.  0 isn't magical when it starts iterating through a zero indexed array.  1 isn't magical when it's an increment. 1 at the start of iterating through that zero indexed array is arbitrary and magical.  Whoever told you you can use 1 and 0 whenever you like without ever explaining yourself lied to you.  If you think you have some amazing power to understand every 1 and 0 go edit some binary.  You'll find plenty of 1's and 0's without any explanation.  Tell us how that works out for you.

Comment: @Eiko: If there is no explanation why the loop starts at the second element, it is virtually guaranteed that some maintenance programmer will change the loop to start at the first element. That is why the numeral 1 is a magic number in this context.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I assumed there would be an immediately visible reason within the context. Like comparing elements with their predecessors (which I thought to be the most-frequent use case to start at 1 - and I fail to see any useful constant name here). If the first element has some ultra-special meaning, the design might be broken, and there should be better fixes than naming that index. I don't say there's never a reason to introduce a variable here. It's just that I think those cases are (or maybe only should be) very rare.

Comment: @svidgen Egads NO.  0 is not a magic number at the start of an index, 1 is not magical when incrementing, 2 is not magical when multiplying.  It's when you put those numbers in other contexts that they become magical and arbitrary.  Don't think you can stick me with 1 with no explanation just because it's a 1.  Think about where it is.

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember what that was a response to. But, I might have just been bitter about the tone of and lack of examples in your answer, whatever i said!

Answer (score 13):

Short answer: the first option is better.

The second option just adds noise.  It is very unlikely that 0+1 helps the reader to understand that it could have been 0 but it is 1.  Much more likely he will be puzzled a brief moment and distracted from what the loop is about.  Especially in a language where all arrays start at 0.

As other mentioned, if you want to stress the fact that the loop starts from 1, not 0, just add a comment.

Answer (score 10):

Don't tell us you're skipping the first item -- we can see that. What isn't obvious is *why*. So.. if it's not obvious from context, tell us why:

```
// array[0] is just a header
for($i=1 ; $i < count(array) ; $i++){
    array[$i];
}
```

Or, if you're comment-averse, something like:

```
$lastHeaderIndex = 0;
for($i = $lastHeaderIndex + 1 ; $i < count(array) ; $i++){
    array[$i];
}
```

Don't use comments and trickery to remind us *how the language works.*

Answer (score 6):

Your example looks contrived. In real world code, the fact the loops needs to start at the second array element is most probably obvious from the following code lines. For example, if the real code looks like this

```
for($i=1 ; $i < count(array) ; $i++){
    array[$i-1]=array[$i];
}
```

there would be no explanation or "0+1" construct needed to make clear why the loop starts at 1 instead of 0.

However, if the code inside the loop does not explain the reasons in such an obvious way (maybe `array[0]` has a special meaning and must be dealt differently than the remaining elements), then add an explaining comment. But before you do this, think twice if you can avoid having `array[0]` this special meaning, and reorganize the surrounding code, which would probably be the better alternative.

Comment: In situations like your example code I like to name the variables "oneBasedIndex" or "zeroBasedIndex".  Though something even more specific for that task would be better.

Answer (score 5):

Never seen option #2, but I like it.  Why?  With option #1 I'd wonder if the programmer forgot that arrays start at 0.  Option #2 makes it clearer that they are deliberately starting at 1.

That said, best in either case to add a comment why you are skipping element.

Or, if you can easily describe why you are starting at one, use a constant.  For example, if looking at command line arguments, something like

```
define ('FIRST_REAL_ARGUMENT', 1);
for ($i=FIRST_REAL_ARGUMENT; ...)
```

Personally, I'd probably just use a comment instead, YMMV.

Comment: I'll say that outside of environments where you're dealing with beginners, I've never had the issue of coworkers forgetting that arrays start at zero. I could see it happening if your work also used a language like MATLAB, but in most environments, I'd assume that the programmer knew what they were doing. And heck, starting a loop at 1 is pretty darn common. There's quite a few reasons to skip the first element of something.

Comment: @Kat That reason needs to be clear for future readers. I'd rather assume that a future programmer doesn't know what it's doing.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt anyone would be confused by the first one. We've all had to do it. So much so that the second one is much more likely to confuse. "Why is there a 0+ there? Did they override the + operator somehow?"

A decent compiler will turn the second one into the first anyway, but it looks like you're using PHP, which is interpreted. So every time the interpreter hits that loop, it's going to have to actually add 0 and 1. Not a big deal, but why make the interpreter do the work?

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable that explain the start point.

You need to "*skip the first element in a zero-based array*", so for example:

```
skipFirstElement = 1;

for($i=$skipFirstElement ; $i < count(array) ; $i++){
    array[$i];
}
```

Comment: I like using a variable but I hate this name.  It doesn't explain WHY you're skipping the first element.  A 1 tells me that anyway.  What good is a variable that needs to be renamed when it's value changes?  I know the OP gave us no clue why so to pick a good name you're going to have to make up a reason.  Without a better name I'd rather have the 1 back.

Comment: @CandiedOrange I agree with you that variable name should be more meaningful, but the problem as it is presented doesn't explain why he wants to skip first value. My point is, I just give an example, the author can choose a name that is best for him.

Comment: Please don't teach this way.  This is confusing enough.  To many coders will reach for the easiest name they can so they can get back to writing hard to understand code.  Seriously, I'd rather deal with the 1 than this.

Answer (score 1):

```
//We are skipping the first element because...    
if ($i==0)  
{    continue;      }
```

If one is obsessive with all loops starting at zero you could use a continue statement.  Add a comment to why you are skipping since normally one wouldn't.

Comment: The problem with this option means that we're going to be evaluating this for every single element, adding n additional comparisons to the loop, while simply skipping the first one through some other method (shifting the array, starting with i = 1, whatever) means only doing the work you need to.

Comment: @KevinFee If you're not dealing with massive arrays, I'd say this simle comparison is not going to be an issue. And I quite like the explicitness of `if first then skip` with a comment saying why. Still without context none of the solutions are "best"

Answer (score -2):

What I'd do is remove the first element before looping. Create a new array if you need to. Explain in a comment why you're doing it. And then just do a simple foreach.

```
$arrayCopy = $array; // in case you don't want to touch the original array
array_shift($arrayCopy); // removing first element because of X reason.
foreach($arrayCopy => $element) { 
    // do stuff
}
```

This way your intent is perfectly clear.

To clarify further you could wrap the code in a method with an appropriate name to make things clearer.

```
function doStuffToAllButTheFirst($array) { // this copies the original array, so there are no sideffects
    array_shift($array);
    foreach($array => $element) { // do stuff }  
}
```

However all of this is still missing context. What do you want to do with the elements? Will you be returning the new array? Do you care about the original and the new array after you `doStuff()`?

Anyway, there's no clear answer here, and deciding how to make the code readable depends greatly on the context.

Comment: I like this because I don't need to deal with indexes now, which is always a plus.

Comment: The disadvantage here is that if you don't want side effects, you need to copy the whole array.

Comment: That's true. But if all of this is in a function or a method, then it shouldn't matter since the array is copied anyway when it's passed in. You can then also name the method appropriately: `doStuffToAllButTheFirstElement($array)`, so you might not need the explicit comment explaining why you're removing the first element.

Comment: Giving `$arrayCopy` a more specific name may also eliminate the need for a comment.

Comment: And what if the reason we're starting at 1 is because we're doing `$array[$i-1] = $array[$i]` or something similar, as per @DocBrown's answer?

Comment: That's different, and intent is clear in that case. Although without any other context all of this is weird. Why would you be doing `$array[$i-1] = $array[$i]`. What you're doing is essentially removing the first element and doubling up the last one. I'd say there are better ways to do that too. I guess the best answer is "It depends". And a properly named method where this code lives would take away a lot of questions.

Comment: This seems horrible to me. Beside all the inefficiency, side effects and inability to solve quite common use cases for `1` (see Kevin Lee's comment), it doesn't make the code any clearer at all. The reader must understand array_shift, what it does, how it works. Maybe this line of code is a bug? Does it modifiy the array or return a new one? Does it insert an element or remove one? Does it change indices or not? I fail to see how using a one-based loop would not be a **huge** improvement in that function (and given its name, instantly understandable).

Comment: The answers to these questions are highly dependent on the context. And as for efficiency, I'd take a foreach over for any day... Any performance difference is near to invisible in most cases.